# How i can allocate null page memory on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, security, null, allocation

Could you please describe me how i can allocate memory in the bottom regions (first 64 Kb)?

So, i know that windows 8 has introduced the new mitigation with disable null page allocation. But there is a way to allow this allocation - http://www.askvg.com/windows-8-comes-with-built-in-16-bit-application-support/.

So, i have been trying this method with a 16-bit application - 16-bit app has runned sucessfully (i also have seen `ntvdm.exe` process in task manager) but my own application couldn't allocate (i also have checked by windbg).

This is flags in my last try (i directly call `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` from ntdll.dll):

```
SIZE_T mappedSize = 0x1000;
PVOID mappedAddress = (PVOID)1;
NtAllocateVirtualMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), &mappedAddress, 0, &mappedSize, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT | MEM_TOP_DOWN, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

Is there any compile option to enable NP allocation or anything else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it is disabled in windows 8 to prevent exploits
seems that you can enable only in 32 bit version of win 8 by enabling 16 bit support (no idea how)